# NLB ARR cross-node setup

Tags: iis, load-balancing, nlb, arr, windows-nlb

Given:

- one ASP.NET web application
- 2 Windows servers with IIS installed (no more servers allowed)

I want to enable load balancing / failover for that application, on both server and application levels.

My plan is:

1) Install the web application on both servers, under IIS.

2) For the server-level load balancing / failover, enable Microsoft NLB

3) For the application level load balancing / failover, I'm tempted to use ARR on each server. So, each server will host both ARR and a web application. Each ARR instance will load-balance requests either locally either to the other server.

Is the last point achievable and viable?

My only constraint: 2 servers, no more.

[image]

Comment: This is a very creative way to fix ARR's broken [health check](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/configuring-application-request-routing-arr/http-load-balancing-using-application-request-routing#step-2---configure-health-check-monitoring) feature. According to the documentation traffic should go to the healthy node, but in my experience when one application pool on one node is brought down (for updating) then ARR only serves 500 errors for any request to the app, rendering all the redundant nodes useless. This is in my opinion a major bug, but I'm afraid it won't be fixed :-(

Answer (score 2):

Typically you would have ARR on the NLB level, directing traffic to the 2nd level Content servers in the farm who serve the same/shared IIS config (same applications).

See [Achieving High Availability and Scalability - ARR and NLB](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/configuring-application-request-routing-%28arr%29/achieving-high-availability-and-scalability-arr-and-nlb)

In your scenario, you don't really *need* ARR - you just want to NLB between 2 content servers, which will allow for 1 server to be down and traffic still go to the server that is up.

ARR will grant you Reverse Proxy / Rewriting functionality, but you can also do URL Rewriting without ARR so, be sure what it is you are wanting to do as ARR is typically only needed for managing farms of servers IMO.

Comment: NLB will for sure provide load-balancing / failover on the server level, however I'm not sure it can provide failover on the application level (the scenario where the server is up but the web app is down). That's why I'm exploring the ARR idea, because it can check the health of the web app.

Comment: No, NLB can't provide app-level failover, since it only runs at OSI level 3.

Comment: Yes, unless you use a powershell script to check for app availability, but that's getting messy/workaround-ish. I prefer to delegate that responsability to ARR.